# How to Declare and use Read/Write Properties

Tags: c#, properties, read-write

I have just started learning C# and in the answers of specific test on the following code it was mentioned that :

> The set property for **Tak** is either missing or incorrect.

The code is consisted of 2 classes.

Class 1 with main:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Takis obj = new Takis();

            obj.Val = 23.4;
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Val);
        }
    }
}
```

Class 2:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Takis
    {
        double val;

        public double Val
        {
            get
            {
                return val;
            }
            set
            {
                val = 3.14;
            }
        }

        public Takis()
        {    
        }
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio i am gettting **NOT ALWAYS** the following:

> 'ConsoleApplication6.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   ConsoleApplication6.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'ConsoleApplication6.vshost.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication6.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. The thread 0x1610 has exited with code 259
>   (0x103). The thread 0x1638 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The thread
>   0x13f4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
>   'ConsoleApplication6.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   ConsoleApplication6.vshost.exe): Loaded
>   'c:\users\stefanos\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\ConsoleApplication6\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication6.exe'.
>   Symbols loaded. The thread 0x1480 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
>   The thread 0x1498 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

Since i am really new to Visual studio and in C# in general i would appreciate it if someone could show me the error or explain to me what is wrong.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Comment: the set method always sets val to 3.14 - this is clearly wrong

Comment: The output you're quoting is irrelevant here. It looks like a typical behaviour.

Comment: Also, for set methods, use 'value' to actually use whatever value is being assigned to set.  `set { val = value; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `set` for property `Val` always sets the property to the same value. Instead, it should most likely set the property to the value entered by the user:

```
set { val = value; }
```

Alternatively, if the intent was for the value to **always** be 3.14 (i.e. read-only), then the setter could be removed and the get would return the value:

```
class Takis
{
    public double Val
    {
        get { return 3.14; }
    }

    public Takis()
    {    
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your time Rufus. Just a clarification. If the intent was for the value to always be 3.14 the code i am providing in my initial post is wrong or just inappropriate?

Comment: A little of both: it's wrong because if the user never tries to set it, it will be '0' when they get it, and inappropriate because 1. you dont' need the backing field (`val`) and 2. exposing a `set` operation implies that you are allowing the user to change the value, which you aren't.

Answer (score 0):

The set in your Val property should be val = value; `value` in C# being a keyword, is the value the property is assigned with instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Your property is not behaving the way that properties normally do. When I set a value like 23.4, I expect that to stick. In your case, your class does not care what *I* set. When I set something, anything really, the property will be 3.14.

Your property should set the value that was given (23.4 in this case). You can do this by using the `value`keyword:

```
    public double Val
    {
        get
        {
            return val;
        }

        set
        {
            val = value;
        }
    }
```